# Django add random character in filename

Tags: django, django-models, django-uploads

I want to upload image and overwrite if the file exist without changing the filename. It's already can overwrite the file but django always add random char on the end filename. How can i overwrite with the same filename ? Here are my code.

```
foto_content_url = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=foto_path)
```

```
def foto_path(instance, filename):
    return '/', filename + '.jpg'])
```

Comment: Best thing would be to delete, but actually deleting makes *not* much sense: it is not known if there aren't other models referring to the same (old) file. That is why Django aims to *keep* the file.

Comment: **792874c226fc8a1974d8b275147f48db2666b0e1ef0a8c95447c5_m4T7Gey.jpg** the filename always like this, but everytime i overwrite the file, the char after underscores is change. i want to keep the filename is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i overwrite with the same filename?

Please *don't*. There is a good reason to do that: you can not know in advance if other model objects are referring to the (old) file. If you would thus override this with new content, now all the records that referred to the old file, will refer to the new file.

Perhaps for now, that scenario is impossible, or very unlikely, but as the application grows, eventually it is possible that you introduce other models with `FileField`s or `ImageField`s that refer to the same file. It is also a security vulnerability: if a person would upload a new document and someone has access to the old document, they now have access to the new document, which is likely not the intended effect.

If you really want to do this, you can check if the file already exists and remove it in that case:

```
import os
import os.path

from django.conf import settings

# bad idea
def foto_path(instance, filename):
    filename = f'/{filename}.jpg'
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    return filename
```

Comment: i've try this, but django always change the filename with **filename_random char**. So everytime i overwrite the file, the filename also changed

Comment: @ad1: so it performs a `os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename))`?

Comment: @ad1: but that is because there is already one with an underscore, so that means the original one was `foo.jpg`, for example, next you uploaded `foo_123.jpg`, and if we then remove `foo.jpg`, it will not remove `foo_123.jpg` of course, but `foo.jpg`, and then reuse that one. So it will only work (and again, not a good idea), if it is done from the start, so without any clashes that already occured.

Comment: yes, i delete first and uploaded new file. but the filename always changed, i want to keep the filename same. is it possible ?

Comment: for example. if i had file `foo.jpg`, and then i delete `foo.jpg` and upload new one with the same name `foo.jpg`. is it possible ?